# Set up multiple servernames that some with SSL and some without SSL support

Tags: nginx

I have two domains point to my server.

One has SSL support, the other has no ssl support.

I'm keeping get the exception by hitting the domain without ssl support.

```
2017/04/05 04:57:11 [error] 23751#0: *23 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 104.59.120.173, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2017/04/05 04:57:11 [error] 23751#0: *24 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 104.59.120.173, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2017/04/05 04:57:16 [error] 23751#0: *25 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 104.59.120.173, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2017/04/05 04:57:47 [error] 23751#0: *26 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 104.59.120.173, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2017/04/05 04:58:41 [error] 23751#0: *27 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 52.27.2.86, server: 0.0.0.0:80



server {
    listen      80 ;
    server_name THIS-DOMAN-WITHOUT-SSL-SUPPORt;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/birchwords_error.log warn;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/birchwords_access.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7617/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 ssl;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    #listen 443  ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/sslSupport_error.log warn;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sslSupport_access.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/sslSupport_me.chian.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/sslSupport.me.key;
    server_name sslSupport.me;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7617/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing ssl from the line: listen 80 ssl;

Comment: you got my fix!! thanks~